# How do I prove that my email was hacked?

Tags: email, spam

I am getting emails and verification from sex sites that I didn't subscribe to. How do stop I them and prove that my email was hacked?

Comment: how to stop them? Put them in the spam folder, create a rule to block them or avoid seeing them. As for "How to prove that the email was hacked", you don't know that your email was hacked, because those are email you received. Anyone could use a random address to subscribe to any website. In a way, that's what verification systems are for.

Comment: Your email wouldn't need to be hacked for you to get emails - anyone could have entered it into a subscription field. It's just spam, basically.

Answer (score 7):

For you to recieve emails from different sites your email does not have to be hacked. Anyone who has your email adress could have signed it up for different accounts or mail lists. Or it is just random spam, that your recieve without anyone signing you up for anything.

If you email has been used to succesfully create an account on a site that requires the user to verify the email by clicking a verification link sent in an email, then that would be a sign that your email is actually hacked.

One way to see if you have been hacked is to see what IP adresses that has been used to access it. Many webmails (e.g. Gmail) provide this service. If you can't find it, perhaps you can ask whoever operates your mail server for a list. If you find suspicious IP addresses there (e.g. from a country you have never been to) that is a sign you have been hacked.

To stop the emails, just mark them as spam. No matter what, you should probably change your email password right away, just in case. I don't think you have been hacked, but it never hurts.

Answer (score -1):

By your short and undetailed question i only can say:

1. Getting emails from other sites that you did not subscribe to does not mean that your email account was hacked. It just means that somebody tried to register/subscribe in those sites using an email account (maybe by a mistake, or maybe intentionally).
2. To stop them: just mark those mails as Spam.
3. As your mail address was not hacked, you don't need to prove it.